# Binding complex property of model to DataGridTextColumn and using Style to set value displayed

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, xaml

Let's say i have the code below...i have a Field class that holds a state and the actual value to display.  I have model that defines an instance of this MyField class named Field1.   In by DataGrid i am binding to this Field1 and using a style to display the value as well as color the background if IsStale is true.  The problem is neither the value, nor the background is being colored.  It appears the problem is that when used as is, the datacontext for the Style is MyData object and not in fact the MyField object, even though i specify the binding as "Field1".  The error being printed out is "BindingExpression path error: 'IsStale' property not found on 'object' ''MyDataModel'".
How can properly bind to a complex property in a Datagrid's cell such that i can use multiple attributes of the bound model?

```
class MyField : BaseModel
{
    private bool _isStale;
    public bool IsStale
    {
        get { return _isStale; }
        set
        {
            if (_isStale == value) return;
            _isStale = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("IsStale");
        }
    }

    private double _value;
    public double Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            if (_value.Equals(value)) return;
            _value = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Value");
        }
    }
}

class MyDataModel
{
    MyField Field1 {get; set;}

    public MyData()
    {
        Field1 = new Field1();

        //when ever underlying property of MyField changes, we need to fire property changed because xaml binds to Field1
        Field1.PropertyChanged += (o,e) =>
            { 
                MyField field = o as MyField;
                if (field!=null)
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("Field1");
            };
    }
}

<DataGridTextColumn Header="Weight" Binding="{Binding Field1}" ElementStyle="{StaticResource DGCellStyle}"/>

Style:
<Style x:Key="DGCellStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Value, Converter={StaticResource NumberFormatConverter}, ConverterParameter=0.00}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsStale}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Pink"/>       
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: How is your data context set?

Comment: Have you tried `{Binding Field1.IsStale}`?

Comment: When you ask a question here, it is generally a good idea to come back and check your responses... when I see that users have been trying to help, but have had no replies for 18 hours, it kind of puts me off trying to answer.

Comment: @Kazuo - the datacontext is set to correctly...otherwise the binding error would have indicated that.  based on the binding error, despite setting the binding of the DataTextColumn to "Field1", within the style context, the datacontext seems to be on the parent object, MyDataModel.
Jim, yes, but then i would not be able to apply the condition to IsStale.
THe only way i've found to resolve this is to use DataGridTemplateColumn and having the template simply be a TextBox